# Is it possible to stop try catch from returning null

Tags: java, try-catch, defensive-programming

If someone calls my method, I want to defensively deal with the problem. Usually I just return `null`.

I decided to implement a `try` `catch` but it looks like I just end up returning `null` anyway.

Can I write my `try` `catch` in such a way that at the end of method it doesn't return `null`?

Sample code, using `peek` on a Stack class.

```
    public T peek()
    {
        T temp = null;

        try
        {
            temp = array[size]; 
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

When called with an empty stack. It will return `null`.

So should I even bother with the `try` `catch` for this kind of case? I am tempted to do this:

```
if(isEmpty())
   return null;
```

If the stack is not empty I want to return the element. If the stack **is** empty then can I avoid returning null if I use the `try-catch`?

Comment: Related: [Avoiding “!= null” statements in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/271526/1065197), just that in this case you avoid from `try/catch` block.

Comment: Do the if-else.   try catch is an awful way to handle normal communications in a program.  Its piss poor performance wise and is just ugly to look at

Comment: what do you want it to return ? And are doing to the try catch to handle IndexOutOfBoundException ?

Comment: Why do you want it to return ?

Comment: I think the more valid question is what do you want to return instead of null?

Comment: If the function peek is failing, then why not let it throw an exception?

Comment: If the stack is not empty I want to return the element. If the stack **is** empty then can I avoid returning null if I use the `try-catch`?

Comment: You avoid returning null if you do not catch anything, but let the calling function catch the exception. Then the function is technically never returning.

Comment: Then why bother with `try-catch` I completely agree with @Totoro.

Comment: Use an [option type](http://java.dzone.com/articles/no-more-excuses-use-null).

Comment: I like the people blindly downvoting the question. Please explain why, I would like to see your reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method has to return something or throw an Exception. If you have an unbounded generic type, then things like null object patterns can't be used, so the options are returning `null`, returning something that contains `T` like `Optional<T>`, or throwing an Exception.

If you don't like the safety of `null`, you can use `Optional`, either from Java 8 or a library. Checked exceptions have a similar safety but are inappropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would approach the problem. By throwing an exception in the peek function, putting the duty of handling that exception in the caller. Why? Because I want an error to cause an explosion as big as possible. The peek method also became smaller. Also as you already agree on, returning null is lame.

```
public T peek() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
{   
  return array[size]; 
}
```

and

```
try
{
  T top = thestack.peek();
  /* Do something with that object */
}
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
{
  /* Do something else */
}
```

Comment: I would like to point out: that is not defensive programming, which is one of my tags.

Comment: Isn't removing makeup defensive? The makeup would be returning even if the function call was exceptional.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to imagine the `array[size]` throwing an Exception, unless array is null or size is outside the length of array. So, you could do something like this -

```
 if (array != null && array.length > size) {
   return array[size - 1]; // assuming your size starts at 1
 }
 return null; // need to return something, if not null you need an option type.
```

**Edit**

Or, using an [Option](http://java.dzone.com/articles/no-more-excuses-use-null) monad - and something like,

```
 if (array != null && array.length > size) {
   return new Some<T>(array[size - 1]); // assuming your size starts at 1
 }
 return new None<T>();
```

Comment: That would return null

Comment: @AndersLindén Was my comment "need to return something, if not null you need an option type." too subtle?

Comment: Sorry, I only saw "return null;" and that was not subtle. Had to read more closely.